# CentOS 7 - root password works only once

Tags: password, root, centos7

I have a very strange issue here. My root password works only once, and as soon as I log out, it ceases to function. Subsequent attempts to log in come back as ‘login incorrect’. I have to drop back down into single-user mode and reset the password to get back into root.

While I can successfully reset the root password when needed, this single-use nature is untenable in the long haul.

Running WHM on this machine, FYI. Been experiencing a sustained hack attempt as of late (280+ CPHulk alerts within the last 24h). CPHulk and LFD are both set to a very paranoid level, all account passwords are GRC-generated and min. 32 characters long.

Comment: Changing the password before logging back out does not fix this issue, FYI. I still cannot log back in after logging out.

Comment: Update: under /var/log/security I find the following: pam_succeed_if(login:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"  So it seems that pam is banning root and su because root has a uid of 0. Huh. And this is from both console (direct root login & su from unprivileged acct) and SSH (su escalation only).

Comment: Great -- so I discover that /bin/su doesn't have the same permissions as in another unix.stackexchange.com article I found, so I corrected it. Now I can’t even log on once. I can change my password in single user mode all I want, and it does NOTHING to let me log in.

Comment: Just discovered that while I can’t su from my unprivileged account, I can still sudo. Small mercies, at least.

Comment: Recovered su abilities by editing the pam config file to trust wheel users. Both lines that are normally commented out.